# how to find the difference between two tables in oracle?

Tags: sql, .net, oracle

I have two tables named `A` and `B` where most of the columns are different and the common column is `name`. Now I want to find the records which are extra in table `A` based on the common field
`name`. How to get these?

One more thing here we have to check is a few names in table `B` have words like `'dummy_'`,`'Test_'` on the beginning which we have to trim. Say for example
table `A` is having `name ='Div_text_col_tar'` and `B` is having `name ='dummy_Div_text_col_tar'` which actually the same. So we have to replace 'dummy_' and 'Test_' from the beginning  of names. How to do it?

I tried like shown below without any luck:

```
SELECT *
FROM A t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
  FROM B t2
  WHERE t1.name = REGEXP_SUBSTR(t2.name,'[^-dummy_|-Test_]+',1,1)
  )
AND t1.status =100
AND t1.floor IN ('1','2','3')
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results woudldreally help.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would go for:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM A t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM B t2
                  WHERE t2.name IN (t1.name, 'dummy_' || t1.name, 'Test_' || t1.name)
                 ) AND
      t1.status = 100 AND
      t1.floor IN (1, 2, 3);  -- presumably, these are numbers, not strings
```

This seems simpler and easier to follow than using regular expressions.

Comment: Given the state of the tables presented by the question I wouldn't make any presumptions regarding the datatype of any of the columns :)